# Laravel 5.4 Middleware Can't define guard

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I have the following files:

routes.php

```
Route::get('client-portal', 'DashboardController@index');
```

DashboardController.php

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth:client-users');
}
```

auth.php

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
    'client-users' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'client-users',
    ],
    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\User::class,
    ],
    'client-users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => \App\Models\ClientPortal\User::class
    ],
],
```

Authenticate.php

```
public function __construct(Guard $auth) {
    $this->auth = $auth;
}

public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ($this->auth->guest()) {
        if ($request->ajax()) {
            return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
        } else {
            dd($this->auth);
            return redirect()->guest('login');
        }
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Whenever I am logged in via `client-users` and navigate to `/client-portal.` The `dd` from `Authenticate.php` returns a `SessionGuard` instance, with the attribute `name` set to `web`

But, I did specify 'auth:client-users' in the constructor of the controller.
So my first thought was the the authenticate middleware was global middleware so I checked that, but it wasn't. If I remove the middleware line from the constructor, the page is displayed.

Does anyone knows where the problem lies?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the instance that is passed to `__construct` does not support the `:` notation for specifying the guard. This `Authenticate.php` was the original file from a previous version of laravel. The `guard` attribute is passed as a third parameter to `handle`.

I have fixed the code as follows:

```
class Authenticate
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        auth()->shouldUse($guard);
        if (auth()->guest()) {
            if ($request->ajax()) {
                return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
            } else {
                return redirect()->guest('login');
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```